# R: Error when trying to transmute a data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

After upgrading R recently, I've starting getting an error when trying transmute a data.table, stating that `:=` can only be used on a quasi quoted argument.  I've searched for a fix but came up short. Reproducible example below using R 3.5.1. Any advice?

```
library(dplyr) #0.7.8
library(data.table)  #1.11.8
library(dtplyr) #0.0.2 

set1 = mtcars %>% data.table()  
transmute(set1 ,mpg2 = mpg*1)
```

> > Error: `:=` can only be used within a quasiquoted argument

Comment: p.s. this is one of my favorite operations. Happens all the time in my scripts. Thanks!

Comment: If those are the latest versions, you should report that [here](https://github.com/hadley/dtplyr/issues).

Comment: Issue reported here:  https://github.com/hadley/dtplyr/issues/62

Comment: Solution here: https://github.com/hadley/dtplyr/issues/62

Answer (score 2):

Solved by using the development version of dtplyr:

https://github.com/hadley/dtplyr/issues/62

Comment: You can click the check mark by the answer to "accept" it, indicating to others that it resolved your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Convert set1 into a tibble.

```
set1 %>% as_tibble() %>% transmute(mpg2 = mpg * 1)
```

Comment: Pretty sure OP is aware of that, but would like to use dtplyr.